# Remove the xmlns in element tag using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Can anyone help me on how to remove the xmlns in the element tag?

XML Input:

```
<gl-cor:entityInformation>
<gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12">
    <gl-cor:phoneNumberDescription contextRef="journal_context">main</gl-cor:phoneNumberDescription>
    <gl-cor:phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</gl-cor:phoneNumber>
</gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber>
<gl-cor:entityFaxNumberStructure xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12">
    <gl-cor:entityFaxNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</gl-cor:entityFaxNumber>
</gl-cor:entityFaxNumberStructure>
<gl-cor:entityEmailAddressStructure xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12">
    <gl-cor:entityEmailAddress contextRef="journal_context">ma.johanna.estrivo@infor.com</gl-cor:entityEmailAddress>
</gl-cor:entityEmailAddressStructure>
```

how will I remove the xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12"?

The expected output should be:

```
<gl-cor:entityPhoneNumber>
<gl-cor:phoneNumberDescription contextRef="journal_context">main</gl-cor:phoneNumberDescription>
<gl-cor:phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</gl-cor:phoneNumber>
```

012-34-56


    ma.johanna.estrivo@infor.com

I'm using the XSLT with this code:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::gl-cor:entityInformation]">
  <!-- change element prefix -->
  <xsl:element name="gl-bus:{local-name()}">
      <!-- process attributes -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
          <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot output elements with a prefix `gl-bus:` without specifying the Namespace of this prefix!

The xmlns:gl-bus must be somewhere in your document - maybe at the root element.

This solution here creates the default namespace - and removes the prefix (well it depend on the rest of you XSLT):

```
<entityInformation xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12">
    <entityPhoneNumber>
        <phoneNumberDescription contextRef="journal_context">main</phoneNumberDescription>
        <phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</phoneNumber>
    </entityPhoneNumber>
    <entityFaxNumberStructure>
        <entityFaxNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</entityFaxNumber>
    </entityFaxNumberStructure>
    <entityEmailAddressStructure>
        <entityEmailAddress contextRef="journal_context">ma.johanna.estrivo@infor.com</entityEmailAddress>
    </entityEmailAddressStructure>
</entityInformation>
```

With this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12"  xmlns:gl-cor="www.any.com" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- change element prefix -->
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12">
            <!-- process attributes -->
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just another possible solution if you want to remove all namespaces, just output only the `local-name()`:

This XSLT will output no namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:gl-bus="http://www.xbrl.org/int/gl/bus/2010-04-12"  xmlns:gl-cor="www.any.com" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <!-- change element prefix -->
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <!-- process attributes -->
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
                <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives following output:

```
<entityInformation>
    <entityPhoneNumber>
        <phoneNumberDescription contextRef="journal_context">main</phoneNumberDescription>
        <phoneNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</phoneNumber>
    </entityPhoneNumber>
    <entityFaxNumberStructure>
        <entityFaxNumber contextRef="journal_context">012-34-56</entityFaxNumber>
    </entityFaxNumberStructure>
    <entityEmailAddressStructure>
        <entityEmailAddress contextRef="journal_context">ma.johanna.estrivo@infor.com</entityEmailAddress>
    </entityEmailAddressStructure>
</entityInformation>
```

Comment: "*if you want to remove all namespaces, you can use the omit-xml-declaration in the XSLT*" Omitting the XML declaration has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you're right. Just edited the answer